# Typical inductance of power (probably wound) resistor

Tags: resistors, inductance

I need a big resistor to dump reactive energy to. But I need it 'fast' since otherwise the input TVS will overload. The situation: parasitic inductance of wiring makes the whole circuit substantially a huge boost converter and for cost reasons I can't put there a leveling capacitor. For reference, nominal 12V in and I see peaks of 90V. So at the moment the plan is to use the equivalent of a braking resistor and dump the excess (there is a whole *water tank* to sink, so power dissipation is not an issue).

A good and cheap part would be something like this http://www.arcolresistors.com/resistors/hs25-aluminium-housed-resistor/ they make both inductive and non-inductive parts but, of course, the non-inductive ones are made on paper only these days.

Do you have any experience on the typical inductance of such a wound inductor? even just as a magnitude order, like, about 100nH or 1µH or whatever.

Comment: For the inductance of that resistor, measure it. For this as an XY problem, what are the specifications for your dump resistor? You could probably make something non-inductively wound quickly, assuming it's a one-off. What's the continuous power rating? What's the single event energy rating? What's the tolerance? What's the maximum inductance? All those are computable for a bulk resistor made with wire.

Comment: your question needs rewriting so somebody downvoted it .I think that you could tart it up so it might get an answer,

Comment: Try searching for non-inductive resistors. Sellers of those may have some comparison information.

Comment: I did some simulation so it's not terribly critical if it's somewhat inductive (like 1 or 2µH)… however I've seen no datasheet stating some value so I hoped someone had experience. Guess I'll buy some and measure them

Comment: Please provide a schematic, operating conditions, etc. It takes a LOT of inductance to exceed the energy rating of a TVS, even at high currents.

Comment: I solved the issue (a combination snubber) but, for the curious, I have about 15µH of feed cable inductance. 2W resistor and a cap fixed the issue

Comment: Ah, there you have it, then.  FYI, even something like a SMAJ24A will handle 15uH charged to, oh, 50 or 60A, somewhere around there. So it really doesn't take much TVS to handle this kind of situation. The RC snubber, you'll have I think around 0.33Ω + 100uF for the same peak voltage as the TVS, is that about right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was asking myself the same question, so I measured some 100 watt power resistors similar to the ones linked in the question with an LCR meter. Here are the results:

- 22R Arcol HS100: 5.9 µH
- 10R Tyco HSC100: 0.6 µH
- 4R7 Arcol HS100: 1.9 µH
- 1R0 Tyco HSC100: 0.15 µH

There are significant inductance differences between the power resistors. Based on this very limited set of measurements you can guess that lower resistance also means lower inductance for a specific power resistor series. But if a couple of µH series inductance matter in your application, you will have to measure the inductance of the power resistor to be sure.

Comment: The arcol parts are without dubt of the wound type! the tyco have probably some special winding method to reduce the inductance. thanks

Comment: Thanks for these measurements, Lars. Have you estimated the contribution of the leads in those measurements? As these resistors are fairly large, the leads will surely have a considerable loop inductance (1e-7 .. 1e-6 H), regardless of the internal winding geometry of the resistive wire. In other terms: Do you see the possibility that your figures are dominated by lead inductance and that component inductance is actually much lower?

Comment: @tobalt The resistors all have the same package size and the measurements were done in the same way. LCR meter with short measurement leads (~10cm) was used. However, I'm not sure if I removed this measurement offset or not. So there could be a 100 nH offset in all measurement, but I don't think it matters much.

Answer (score 0):

Myself and others have used Caddock resistors for for dummy loads.
They are have pretty good low inductance loads up to about 200 MHz.
https://www.qsl.net/in3otd/ham_radio/dummy_loads/Caddock_MP9100.html